# New Google Recaptcha (no captcha) works locally, not on live site - error 500

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, captcha, recaptcha

My captcha (the new one "no captcha" from google) works as expected on localhost, but on the live site I get an error 500 when trying to validate it(I've got it in the login page), sorry not providing more info about 500 error, it only tells me that is an error at line 16 of jquery.min.js and breaks at my $.ajax line of the verifyCallback function.

Here is my code in the client side:

```
var verifyCallback = function (result) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Account/ResponseCaptcha/',
        type: 'POST',
        traditional: true,
        data: { captchaResponseClient: result },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
};

var widgetCaptcha;
var resp;
var onloadCallback = function () {
    widgetCaptcha = grecaptcha.render('captcha', {
        'sitekey': 'here goes my key, not shown for privacy',
        'callback': verifyCallback,
        'theme': 'light'
    });
};
```

And here my server side verification (on server this code runs well):

```
<HttpPost()>
Public Sub ResponseCaptcha(ByVal captchaResponseClient As String)
    Dim webclient As New WebClient()

    Dim response = webclient.DownloadString(
        String.Format("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={0}&response={1}",
        "my secret key..",
        captchaResponseClient
    ))
    Dim recaptchaResult As New RecaptchaResult

    _responseCaptcha = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RecaptchaResult)(response).Success

End Sub
```

Could you give me a hand?

UPDATE:

Solved the error. It was a matter of configuration of the proxy under web.config file.